# Updating a Rails Engine Version Number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems, rails-engines, gemspecs

In a rails engine when should the version number in *lib/myengine/version.rb* be updated?

Should it be updated before every git push?

If so, can/should the version number be updated with some automation, rather than changing the number in the file every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That version number represents the version of your gem.  So, if you publish a new release of your engine (using either `gem publish` or bundler's `rake release`), you need to update `version.rb`.

This doesn't have anything to do with `git`, so you can do `git push` without updating the `version.rb`.

Though maintaining a version number for your gem is not required, it is convention to follow semantic versioning patterns: http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#semantic-versioning

Comment: Thanks Sean! I'm new to making rails engines so I wasn't sure what best practice was.